# Android: wait subthread

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to wait for the completion of a sub-thread to determine the login status. But I'm not familiar with how to write internal classes, so I'd like to ask how to write code to wait for a child thread to finish execution in the login function.

```java
public class LoginDataSource {

    static LoggedInUser loggedUser = new LoggedInUser();

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

        try {
            // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
            loginMyBlog(username, password, loggedUser);           
            if (loggedUser.isLogStatue()) {                
                return new Result.Success<>(loggedUser);
            } else {              
                return new Result.Failed("pass incorrect");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }


    private void loginMyBlog(String usernames, String passwords, LoggedInUser userAuth) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                // Code for sending network requests
                //...

                //Code to determine if the login is successful
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();                    
                    final String responseData = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject
                            .parseObject(responseData);
                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                    if (code.equals("20000")){
                    // login success
                        JSONObject dataObject = JSONObject.parseObject(jsonObject.getString("data"));
                        userAuth.setId(dataObject.getInteger("id"));
                        userAuth.setIntro(dataObject.getString("intro"));
                        userAuth.setLogStatue(true);
                        Log.d("test", "登录成功"+userAuth);
                    }else if (code.equals("51000")){
                        // login failed
                        userAuth.setLogStatue(false);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // network err
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a thread anyway? The thread is completely useless in this case since you have to wait for it to complete right after you create it.

Comment: Some questions: (1) does "login()" should be called from AnyThread or only from UiThread/MainThread? (2) can "login()" be blocking?